# Programmer's Guide for Pic Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, manual

I'm looking for programmer's guide for PIC16F1947 micro but so far couldn't find such manual. Is it available online? If yes, where can I find it?

I've searched microchip.com and Google but didn't see such manual.

By programmer's guide I mean a manual for us, the programmers. The manual should contain how to write programs for PIC micros (e.g., how to write interrupts, what does __config do, which files to include etc).

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I'll use MPLAB IDE 8.46, ICD 3 and HI-TECH C Compiler 9.81.

Comment: This is probably your best bet as a starting point for details on that specific chip: http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en538146. Specifically the "PIC16F193X/LF193X/PIC16F194X/LF194X/PIC16LF190X Memory Programming" document. If you want an overall document for PIC programming are you looking to work in ASM or one of the C-style compilers? If so you'll need to specify what tool(s) you're working with.

Comment: It depends a lot on the compiler and development environment you are using (or planning to use). Have you already picked one? Which one is it?

Comment: @Matt, that's not what i want. by 'programming' i meant writing code.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473454/whats-the-best-resource-to-learn-assembly-language-for-pic-microcontrollers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This manual will probably work as a starting point. It talks about things like interrupts and generally how to perform various simple tasks: http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eblock/db/downloads/PICmanual2.pdf

You will still need the datasheet and/or the programming guide to perform more complex tasks. Those documents will provide the necessary details to drive functionality on your specific chip. Here's a link to the programming guide: http://microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en538146

Answer (score 1):

I found a data sheet for the PIC16F1947 catalogued here; not sure if it's the right one:

http://www.alldatasheet.com/view.jsp?Searchword=PIC16F1947

(Passing this site on, as even though it's not the manufacturer's site, it's a really good resource for finding data sheets; I'm not affiliated.)

---

ETA: Hmm, well, it *used* to be a good site, but it seems less so, now..  Leaving this here in case it is still useful.